Automation between Slack and Google Sheets
I am having difficulty finding an efficient way to use Zapier to send an alert to Slack's Y channel based on Google Sheets activity.
I have about 20 separate Google Sheets documents and for each of them I want to receive a notification if 3 days passes without the addition of a new row.
I have a Zapier subscription and tried creating a zap that checks for a “New Spreadsheet Row” event and if there is it sends a message to Slack, but it didn't work.

How can I do this?

This question seems to be about using Zapier. As it's a cloud service, the question is off-topic in [su].
